# Cast as decimal not giving me correct results

Tags: sql-server, casting

I get a result of  0.00000 from the following cast

```
Secs_in_month = 2592000
total_fault_time_sum = 99

cast(((Secs_in_Month - total_fault_time_sum) / Secs_in_Month) as decimal(18,5)) AS availability
```

the result should be 0.99996

any ideas on what I am doing wrong here ?

Many thanks

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast it before division:

```
cast((Secs_in_Month - total_fault_time_sum) as decimal(18,5)) / Secs_in_Month AS availability
```

Otherwise, you're still doing integer division, and just casting the result.